# Different graphs of a value from same server

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, influxdb

I'm testing monitoring methods for my kafka server with grafana. Currently I have 2 dashboards with 2 data sources; Prometheus and InfluxDB. But the graphs they show are slightly different from each other. For example, "Bytes Out" graph for Prometheus and InfluxDB are respectively given:

[image: Prometheus]

[image: InfluxDB]

Metrics for Prometheus: `sum without(topic)(rate(kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_bytesout_total{job="kafka",topic!=""}[5m]))`

Metrics for InfluxDB:

```
SELECT last("FiveMinuteRate") FROM "BytesOutPerSec" WHERE time >= now() - 6h and time <= now() GROUP BY time(30s) fill(null);
SELECT last("FiveMinuteRate") AS "topic_t1" FROM "BytesOutPerSecPerTopic" WHERE ("typeName" = 'type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesOutPerSec,topic=t1') AND time >= now() - 6h and time <= now() GROUP BY time(30s) fill(null);
SELECT last("FiveMinuteRate") AS "topic_t2" FROM "BytesOutPerSecPerTopic" WHERE ("typeName" = 'type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesOutPerSec,topic=t2') AND time >= now() - 6h and time <= now() GROUP BY time(30s) fill(null)
```

What could be the reason? Which one should I trust? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are the same graph. Look at the Y-axis scale.